# Styling only the newest line of output in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple app that outputs messages when some actions are performed on a page, and it is done through the javascript createElement function, what I want to do is add a special style to only the newest message, so if a newer messages comes up the old newest message would revert to the old style. Is there any way to do this? when I createElement it seems all the divs would have to have the same class, and anything I try just applies the style to all the messages.

So is there anything to use in CSS that allows me to only apply a style to the newest member of a certain class?

here is how I create the new messages

```
function selfMsg(message) {
    const msg = document.createElement('div');
    msg.style.cssText = 'display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;background-color:aquamarine';
    msg.innerText = message;
    display.append(msg);
}
```

but all this does is style all the divs the same style, and I have no idea how I'm supposed to remove the style if a newer message comes up.

Ideally I'm looking for something in CSS that I can use in my stylesheet file that can target an entire class like how ".classnamehere" works, but only applies the style to the newest member of that class.

Comment: Can you add your code, to provide better understanding

Comment: added. when a new div gets added to the page I want the new div to have a special style and the old div with that style to no longer have that style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the container your divs are in, you can use CSS last:child (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) like this:

So if your container has the class `display`, you'd do

```
.display div:last-child {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color:aquamarine    
}
```

In case you don't know how to use this outside of javascript, simply wrap the above code in a `style` tag and add it to the `head` of your html document.

For clarity and possibly-upcoming-changes reasons, i highly suggest giving all of your divs a class on creation and using that instead of just `div` in the CSS. It's just easier to maintain that way.

```css
.message-wrapper .message:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-wrapper">
  <div class="message">Message 1</div>
  <div class="message">Message 2</div>
  <div class="message">Message 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :last-child pseudo selector. Something like:

```
.display div:last-child{
  // your style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your messages like this:

```
msg.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Then use a `css` selector to only apply styles to the last element of this type

```
div.mystyle:last-of-type {
    /* ... your styles */
}
```

Here's an example you can play with, from w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_last-of-type

If you want to use pure javascript, you could use `element.removeAttribute("style")` or `element.style.cssText = null`, but you would have to keep track of the previous message elements, **or** get ALL messages and loop through them, removing the style from all before adding the newest element. I'd recommend just using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line
The key is the `:last-child` pseudo class

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const target = document.getElementById('add-target')
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  const text = document.createTextNode(`#${target.querySelectorAll('div').length+1}`)
  div.appendChild(text)
  target.appendChild(div)
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.container > div {
  --bg-in: lightgray;
  --bg-out: transparent;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  -webkit-animation: anim-out 1s .3s both;
          animation: anim-out 1s .3s both;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  -webkit-animation: anim-in 1s both;
          animation: anim-in 1s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-in {
  from {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
  to {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
}

@keyframes anim-in {
  from {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
  to {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-out {
  from {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
  to {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
}
@keyframes anim-out {
  from {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
  to {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="container" id="add-target">
  <div>#1</div>
  <div>#2</div>
  <div>#3</div>
</div>
```

Or—a little bit more sophisticated—with `animationend` event to implement a fadeoutafter some time

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const target = document.getElementById('add-target')
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add('in')
  const text = document.createTextNode(`#${target.querySelectorAll('div').length+1}`)
  div.appendChild(text)
  target.appendChild(div)
})

document.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
  e.target.classList.add('out');
  e.target.classList.remove('in');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.container > div {
  --bg-in: lightgray;
  --bg-peak: gray;
  --bg-out: transparent;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.container > div.out {
  -webkit-animation: anim-out 1s 5s both ease-out;
          animation: anim-out 1s 5s both ease-out;
}
.container > div.in {
  -webkit-animation: anim-in 1s both;
          animation: anim-in 1s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
  25% {
    background-color: var(--bg-peak, black);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
}

@keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
  25% {
    background-color: var(--bg-peak, black);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-out {
  from {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
  to {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
}
@keyframes anim-out {
  from {
    background-color: var(--bg-in, pink);
  }
  to {
    background-color: var(--bg-out, white);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="container" id="add-target">
  <div>#1</div>
  <div>#2</div>
  <div>#3</div>
</div>
```